# Crsytal Reports: VS 2005 Deployment

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

Hi I am using the CR that was included with VS 2005.  It works fine locally but when I deploy to my production machine I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Not sure what this means; but googling leads me to believe this is a problem a lot of people have had.  I was wondering if anyone knew any solutions to this?  I have installed the CR Runtime on my production server which I got from the Bootstrapper folder of my local machine.  Other than that I am not sure what I am missing?  I do not have a license for Crystal Reports.  ( Do I need one? )  Thank you.

Comment: What version of that assembly is installed on your production box?

Comment: How do you deploy your application?
1.) Click-once?
2.) Setup project?

Comment: I assume you installed "CRRedist2005_x86.msi". Are there any other versions of crystal already on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Build options for the assembly to copy local True.